# Template deduction for variadic template lambda arguments

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, generic-lambda

Given the following variadic template:

```
template<typename... Params>
void fun(void(*f)(Params...), Params... params) {
  f(params...);
}

int main() {
  fun(+[](int a, int b) {}, 2, 3);
}
```

For now when invoking `fun` with a lambda I need to specify types of all lambda arguments explicitly. It seems redundant since the `int, int` could be deduced from `2, 3`. Is there a way to make it more concise and automatic?

I would like the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
template<typename... Params>
void fun(void(*f)(Params...), Params... params) {
  f(params...);
}

int main() {
  fun(+[](auto a, auto b) {}, 2, 3);
}
```

I am compiling with `g++ 5.4.0` and `-std=c++14`.

Comment: You have a problem with typing `int` instead of `auto`?

Comment: @Brian Yes, cuz it requires me to deduce that it is `int`. It can be anything longer to make it more dramatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the function by `T` instead of by pointer:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
void fun(T f, Params... params) {
  f(params...);
}

int main() {
  fun([](auto a, auto b) {}, 2, 3);
}
```

That way, the compiler can choose which overload is the right to call at the call site instead if inside the `+` operator. Just as said in the comment, there is no `+` operator defined for generic lambdas anyway.

---

Alternatively, you can disable the compiler from trying to deduce `Params` from the function pointer by using an identity alias, but I **really don't recommend it**. Anyway, here you go:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template<typename... Params>
void fun(void(*f)(identity_t<Params>...), Params... params) {
  f(params...);
}

int main() {
  //  v----- no unary +. That operator is not defined for generic lambdas.
  fun([](auto a, auto b) {}, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no `+` operator for non-generic lambdas either. The built-in `+` operator is used, but the lambda is thereby coerced to a pointer using its conversion operator to function pointer.